# Diferenças entre SELECT, count e empty para trabalhar dados da DB

Tags: php, mysql, desempenho

Eu, por curiosidade gostava de saber as diferenças entre 3 coisas aparentemente iguais para contar (rows, linhas) e obter dados de uma tabela, em MySql/PHP:

1ª: Retornar o número de rows primeiro, e só depois trabalhar os dados dessas rows, EX com PDO:

```
function count_rows() {
    $sql = ("SELECT * FROM `{$table}`");
    $data = $this->_db->prepare($sql);

    $data->execute();
    $data_rows = $data->rowCount();
    return $data_rows;
}

function select_data() {
    $sql = ("SELECT * FROM `{$table}`");
    $data = $this->_db->prepare($sql);

    $data->execute();
    return $data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}


if(count_rows() > 0) {
    //trabalhar dados
    echo select_data[0]->id;

}
```

2ª: Apenas utilizar a função para selecionar os dados, e depois usa-los no PHP usando a função `count` para verificar se existem dados (rows), o que vai fazer com que a função count_rows acima seja dispensável (pelo menos neste exemplo), conferimos também se o array (rows) retornado é vazio:

```
function select_data() {
    $sql = ("SELECT * FROM `{$table}`");
    $data = $this->_db->prepare($sql);

    $data->execute();
    return $data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}

if(count(select_data()) > 0) {
    //trabalhar dados
    echo select_data()[0]->id;

}
```

3ª: Desta maneira não contamos, mas podemos ver se o array (rows) retornado da função `select_data()` está vazio ou não, o que já faz com que possamos trabalhar os dados recebidos:

```
function select_data() {
    $sql = ("SELECT * FROM `{$table}`");
    $data = $this->_db->prepare($sql);

    $data->execute();
    return $data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}

if(!empty(select_data())) {
    //trabalhar dados
    echo select_data()[0]->id;

}
```

O que eu queria saber com esta questão é se existe alguma vantagem/desvantagem no uso de alguma delas (sabendo claramente que a ultima não serve para contar, mas já verifica se existe informação), ou podemos usar qualquer uma consoante as nossas necessidades sem qualquer entrave?

Comment: Olá, eu não entendi muito bem, mas vantagens/desvantagens isso vai depender de como seu script funciona e o que ele vai fazer, por exemplo se vc fizer uma consulta no db e este retorne vazio, e logo apos tenha um laço, provavelmente vai exibir algum erro, entao melhor tratar os dados antes de sair fazendo um laço onde nao tem dados. mas vc poderia explicar melhor sua pergunta? agora eu to curioso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade nenhuma dessas opções citadas na pergunta tem um bom desempenho. Pois está realizando a operação duas vezes, no `if` e na manipulação dos dados. Melhor é armazenar todo o resultado em uma variável e trabalhar em cima dela:

```
function select_data() {
    $sql = ("SELECT * FROM `{$table}`");
    $data = $this->_db->prepare($sql);

    $data->execute();
    return $data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}


if(count($dados = select_data()) > 0) {
    //trabalhar dados
    echo $dados[0]->id;
}
```

Assim a consulta será executada apenas uma vez, e você terá todos os valores na variável `$dados`, sem precisar buscar os dados uma vez para testar a quantidade e outra vez para trabalhar.

O PHP também já realiza operações lógicas em cima de valores, por exemplo:

```
Array('Hello World') == TRUE
Array()              == FALSE
NULL                 == FALSE
0                    == FALSE
1                    == TRUE
'0'                  == FALSE
'1'                  == TRUE
```

Baseado nisso podemos então utilizar da seguinte forma:

```
if($dados = select_data()) {
    //trabalhar dados
    echo $dados[0]->id;
}
```

O método [`fetchAll` do PDO](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetchall.php) pode retornar um *array* vazio, ou *false* em caso de falha. Então em ambos os casos o resultado será igual. Utilizando uma função como `count` você obtem o mesmo resultado, porém com um pouco de código a mais.